# SQL convert column to float in where clause

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have this column in my database table and its a string. I didnt make this table and I cant change the data type.

However I need to convert it to a float in my where clause so I can compare it against a float.

I have tried the casting my column as a float:

```
sql += " AND CAST (ec.bedrooms as float) <= " + id.beds.Max().Split('-')[1] + " AND CAST (ec.bedrooms as float) >= " + id.beds.Min().Split('-')[0];
```

but that didnt work as I got this error:

```
An error occurred while reading from the store provider's data reader. See the inner exception for details
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is what is generated for that section

```
AND CAST (ec.bedrooms as float) <= 3 AND CAST (ec.bedrooms as float) >= 2

"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Error converting data type nvarchar to float.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.StoreRead()"}}
```

Comment: Please show the *actual* generated query.

Comment: And the stack trace

Comment: You should really be using parameters to build the SQL query.

Comment: **[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!!!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)**, I am sorry to shout, but this is so important, not only for keeping you safe from SQL injection attacks, but for performance, and to avoid type conversion issues. There no good reason not to use parameterised queries. Now, that I have got that out of my system, please can you post the details of the inner exception, since this will contain the actual error message that you need to fix.

Comment: You must have values in your table that can't be converted to float. If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you could replace `CAST` with [`TRY_CAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) which will return `NULL` for the records that can't be converted rather than throwing an error. This is a bit of a cover up though, and is no replacement for tracking down the invalid records, correcting them, and finding a dba that can make changes to the datatype and getting it changed from nvarchar to a numeric type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your ec.bedrooms is having non-numeric values... You can check like below:

```
sql += " AND CAST (iif(isnumeric(ec.bedrooms)>0,ec.bedrooms,null) as float) <= " + id.beds.Max().Split('-')[1] + " AND 
CAST (iif(isnumeric(ec.bedrooms)>0,ec.bedrooms,null) as float) >= " + id.beds.Min().Split('-')[0];
```